# Getting HttpHostConnectException while starting/stopping the appium server

Tags: java, appium

Getting ExceptionHttpHostConnectException while running Appium Server start/stop script. I tried changing the port number but I'm still getting the same exception. Does anyone know what the issue is?

I'm running the following:

- selenium-android-driver.jar
- java-client-4.1.2 (1).jar
- selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

CODE:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Serverhort {
     static AndroidDriver driver;
     private static Process process;
    public static String APPIUM_NODE_FILEPATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe";
    public static String APPIUM_SERVERSCRIPT_FILEPATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js";
public static String APPIUMSERVERSTART = "\"" + APPIUM_NODE_FILEPATH + "\" \"" + APPIUM_SERVERSCRIPT_FILEPATH + "\" ";

    public static void startServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    process = runtime.exec(APPIUMSERVERSTART);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    if (process != null)
    {
    System.out.println("Appium server started");
    }
    }

    /**
    * DOCUMENT ME!
    */
    public static  void stopServer()
    {
    if (process != null)
    {
    process.destroy();
    }
    System.out.println("Appium server stop");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
        stopServer();
    startServer();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ccdcb242");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "ANDROID");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sears.android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.sears.activity.MenuDrawerActivity");
driver =  new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"), capabilities);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    stopServer();
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4727 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'SHI58495EU1003F', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
    at Utility.Serverhort.main(Serverhort.java:60)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4727 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
```

Comment: What are the node configuration parameters that you are passing to the server?

Comment: KristapsMežavilks : http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub

Comment: I mean `nodeConfig` parameter file contents.
It seems that you just launch Appium server without any configuration.

Comment: yes . I am just running this script without configuration. Can you please provide me steps to configurate parameter in nodeconfig

Comment: C'mon. Google it. There are plenty of information.
https://discuss.appium.io/t/launching-and-stopping-appium-server-programmtically/700/2